Remove + from column
How do I remove the + in the 3rd column and save the output to a new file?
2022-03-17 00:01:00,  55.0,+30.9, 72.3
2022-03-17 00:01:30,  55.0,+30.8, 72.3
2022-03-17 00:02:02,  53.0,+30.9, 72.4
2022-03-17 00:02:33,  50.0,+30.9, 72.3
2022-03-17 00:03:04,  50.0,+30.9, 72.0
2022-03-17 00:03:35,  54.0,+31.0, 72.1
2022-03-17 00:04:06,  55.0,+30.9, 72.2


What have you tried, and how did it fail exactly? Are columns delimited by commas or whitespace (or both) in your example?

clearly a homework question and not Ubuntu related

@kos I'm somewhat guided by Thomas Ward's comment under this meta answer I don't see that the situation has changed any.

@graham I apologize, I thought "not Ubuntu related" was referring to the question itself, not to "homework questions" in general, yeah those are off-topic, absolutely (I removed my comment)

Why "homework"? I really don't understand this. This sort of issue is very common, there is nothing suggesting homework here. And text parsing questions are entirely on topic. It's not a good question as it shows no effort, and isn't well defined, but it isn't off topic.

If you can simply remove all +, you could do:
tr -d '+' file > new.file

If you need to limit to a specific field of the file, and assuming your fields are defined by ,, you can do:
$ awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{ gsub(/\+/,"",$3)}1' file
2022-03-17 00:01:00,  55.0,30.9, 72.3
2022-03-17 00:01:30,  55.0,30.8, 72.3
2022-03-17 00:02:02,  53.0,30.9, 72.4
2022-03-17 00:02:33,  50.0,30.9, 72.3
2022-03-17 00:03:04,  50.0,30.9, 72.0
2022-03-17 00:03:35,  54.0,31.0, 72.1
2022-03-17 00:04:06,  55.0,30.9, 72.2

As before, to redirect to a new file, just add > newfile to the end.
